# A curve with given curvature property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Find equation of curve where radius of curvature $PC$ is proportional to $PX^2$. Its normal intersects x-axis at X. The above plot is obtained after a numerical calculation.

EDIT1 &2:

If $\phi$ is slope of tangent

$$ \sin \phi\, \frac {d \phi }{dy} = k \,\big({\frac{\cos \phi}{y}\big)}^2 $$

Substitution $$ \cos \phi =u ;\quad \frac { du }{u^2} =k \frac{ dy}{y^2}$$

Integrate with initial condition at ($ y = a,\phi=0 $)

$$  \frac { 1 }{u}- \frac { k }{y}=1 -\frac{k}{a} $$

Thanks in advance for the next closed form integration.

Comment: Have you tried anything, e.g. translate the problem into a differential equation.

Comment: I think you need a minus sign on the left hand side since $\sin\phi\,d\phi=-d(\cos\phi)$. When you integrate (take, say, $k=1$, you end up with $1/u+1/y=const.$ If now you start your curve at $(0,1)$ with $\phi=0$ you get $y=\cos\phi/(2-\cos\phi)$. This does not seem to be a circle. Indeed, this is a differential equation in desguise, given that $\cos\phi=dx/ds$.

Comment: My query is..on integration to recognize to what family of equations the catenary ( k<0) or circle (k>0) become special cases...

Comment: @GReyes.  Constant of proportionality k of either sign, resulting in supersets of catenaries/circles on integration.